# Save JSON in MySQL Workbench issue

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-workbench

I have the following string:

```
"test\n\ntest\n\ntest3"
```

The string is part of a JSON value that I am inserting into a table in MySQL Workbench. After the data is inserted the string gets converted into the following when I check the data in the table:

```
 "test
 
 test
 
 test3"
```

Which then makes my JSON invalid. I want MySQL Workbench to just keep the data exactly as I send it, instead of converting the "\n" into new lines in the table.

Is there some way to tell MySQL Workbench to stop formatting the data?

Comment: How do you insert that line? Do you escape `\n` to be `\\n`?

Comment: That is the problem.  You need to escape the double quotes.

Try this:                     \"